# Whether can we initializing vectors using [] rather than push_back()

Tags: c++, vector, stl, stdvector

As part of vectors, using [] I am not able to initialize.

```
std::vector<int> vectorVar;
vectorVar[0] = 0;
```

Seeing undefeined behaviour.

Whereas able to use only if its already created.

```
vectorVar.push_back(0);
vectorVar[0] = 5;
```

But in case of map able to use even if there is no entry.

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> mapVar;
mapVar[0] = vectorVar;
```

Please clarify.

Thanks & Regards
Vishnu Beema

Getting undefined behavior if "vectorVar[0] = 0;"

Comment: What do you think `mapVar[90210] = vectorVar;` would do, and what should `vectorVar[90210] = 5;` should do? Obviously the answer cannot be "the same" or we would not have two different classes for it.

Comment: `std::map` will add a new element if it doesn't already exist. That's how it can provide a reference to the contained type via `operator[]`. `std::vector`, on the other hand does _NOT_ automatically grow itself when you index out of range, and thank goodness for that.

Comment: Note that there are many useful ways to initialize vectors. If you have an example that's more specific than this toy example, we can help you. I can't think of a single time in ~30 years of writing C++ that I've wanted or needed to do what you're asking here.

Comment: Note that neither of those are initializations, they are assignments (initialization means a very specific thing in C++) and that "undefined behaviour" is not any specific behaviour that you can recognize. You can't observe the absense of undefined behaviour, and it often goes unnoticed for a long time (sometimes forever).

Comment: _Getting undefined behavior if "vectorVar[0] = 0;"_ I suspect you're getting a popup from the MSVC debugging runtime.  Don't rely on that, other implementations (and MSVC Release builds) may silently trample on memory you don't own, after which, all bets are off.

Comment: It's the way different containers are designed. A `std::vector`'s `operator[]()` function doesn't, by design, check if the supplied index is valid, nor does it resize the vector to make the supplied index valid - instead, an invalid index is specified to give undefined behaviour. Whereas a `map`s `operator[]()` checks if the supplied key/index exists in the map and, if it doesn't, creates a new map entry for the supplied key. These design choices reflect different manners in which different container types are typically used in practice.

Comment: For initialization of a vector, you can do e.g. `std::vector<int> vectorVar = {3,7,11};`

Answer (score 7):

`std::map::operator[]` is somewhat different from other `[]` because its not just element access. It is more.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

When no element is in the map with the given key then one is inserted into the map.

Vectors do not work like this. [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) does not insert elements into the vector.

In general you need to get a reference where you can look things up. C++ is too complicated to remember everything. I suggest https://en.cppreference.com/ because its usually rather close to the wording in the standard but at the same time very readable.

Comment: Interesting to contrast `at` with `operator[]`. `at` for vectors and maps are rather closer in that `map::at` does not insert a new key, instead it throws an exception, just like `vector::at`.

Comment: As an addition to this answer it is also worth noting: A `map` is a key-value container, and the existence of `myMap[300]` does not imply that keys 0 through 299 must exist. On the other hand, a `vector` is a contiguous container, and if `myVector[300]` exists then the `myVector` MUST also contain indexes 0 through 299.

Comment: Another important difference: `myMap["Bob"]` is fine and makes straightforward intuitive sense (since `"Bob"` acts as a key), whereas I struggle to even imagine a situation where `myVector["Bob"]` makes any kind of sense.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<T>` is a container of elements stored contiguously.

```
std::vector<int> v;
v[5] = 1;
```

The code above would require inserting 0 or whatever into `v[0]` till `v[4]`. This is definitely not what is expected thus forbidden.

`std::map<T>` is a sparse container,

```
std::map<int> m;
m[5] = 1;
```

The code above inserts just a single element into a map.